# How to get contents between two strings using same number of repeated characters?

Tags: sed, regular-expression

Essentially, I'm trying to get the content between two string, but that use the same character repeated N time, like so:

```
===
This is a test
===

====
Another test
====

==
Last test
==
```

The above is just an example of course. Here what I tried and their result:

```bsh
sed -u '/==/!d;s//&\n/;s/.*\n//;:a;/==/bb;$!{n;ba};:b;s//\n&/;P;D' testfile
```

Give

```
=
This is a test

=




Another test






Last test
```

If I were to use only one of the above in the `testfile`:

```
Last test
```

This would give the wanted result (albeit with too many added newlines but that's fine for this example).

The above works only if there a single instance of those repeated characters or if it is a pair of unique strings enclosing the content...

How can I get the content between two strings using the same number of repeated characters? I prefer to use either `grep`, `sed` or `awk` for this.

Comment: Can your input have different number of `=` in between two equal number of `=` characters? In other words, would `sed -nE '/^=+$/,//{//!p}' testfile` fail for your usecase?

Comment: no, most "content" between the example two string wouldn't have any of the character used as "enclosing". :) @Sundeep

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## tl;dr

```
$ sed '/^==*$/,//{//!p};d' testfile
This is a test
Another test
Last test
```

---

On first look, a simple range could print all pairs (no loops needed):

```
$ sed -n '/^=/,//p' testfile
===
This is a test
===
====
Another test
====
==
Last test
==
```

That prints every line between a line that starts with `=` and the next repeated regex (`//`).

That could be improved to a line that **only** contains `=`: `/^==*$/`.

And to remove all the markers:

```
$ sed -n '/^==*$/,//H;${x;s/\n==*//g;s/^\n//;p}' testfile
This is a test
Another test
Last test
```

Or, in a shorter form:

```
$ sed -n '/^==*$/,//{//d;p}' testfile
This is a test
Another test
Last test
```

To match an exact number of `=` change the regex to:

```
$ sed -n '/^==$/,//{//d;p}' testfile
Last test
```

And, to avoid the `-n` option:

```
$ sed '/^==$/,//{//!p};d' testfile
Last test
```

---

In awk it could be done like:

```
$ awk 'p==0 && /^==*$/ {p=1;next}
       p==1 && /^==*$/ {p=0}
       p          
      ' testfile

This is a test
Another test
Last test
```

Or, in a bit less explicit form:

```
awk ' /^==*$/ { p = !p ; next}
      p
    ' testfile
```

Answer (score 8):

We use the **awk** utility to employ  flip flop logic to toggle from on state to off as shown:

```
$ awk -v str="==" '
      $0""==str{f=!f;next};f
' testfile
Last test
```

---

Using Posixly **sed** constructs we can implement the flip flop logic:

```
sed -ne '
  /^==$/{
    x;        # access state info from hold
    s/^$/0/;  # initialize state
    y/01/10/; # toggle state
    x;        # save state in hold
    d;        # next
  }
  G;/\n1/P
' testfile
```

---

Employing the GNU version of the stream editor **sed** in its extended mode `-E`

```
$ sed -Ee '
    $!N; /^(\S)\1+\n/!D
    :loop
        $d;N
        s/^(.*)\n(.*)\n\1$/\2/;t
    bloop
' testfile
This is a test
Another test
Last test
```

Notes:-

- Keep a two-line pattern space by means of the `N` command.
- keep rejecting lines until we meet the golden line (=> one in which the first portion of the pattern space comprises only a single type of nonwhitespace char)
- once such a line is found, then we loop till we meet its exact replica atleast two lines down the road. And we"re done finding the first set.
- This process repeats till we hit the eof.

---

Using the flip-flop operator `...` in **perl** we can do like as shown:

```
perl -lne 'print if 
 /^(\S)\1+$(?{$a=$_})/ ... $_ eq $a and $_ ne $a;
' testfile
```

---

For fixed predetermined strings to search for is even simpler , for then we don't have to craft a regex rather a string equality test would suffice:

```
$ perl -nlse 'print if
    $_ eq $a ... $_ eq $a and $_ ne $a;
' -- -a=== testfile
```

---

```
$ sed -Ee '
    /^==$/!d
    $!N
    :a
        $d;N
        s/^(.*)\n(.*)\n\1$/\2/;t
    ba
' testfile
```

Comment: Essentially, I would prefer if this only output *one* result depending on the number of repeated char used. eg: if you were to use the pattern for getting the string "Another test", then by using "====" it would only output every string being enclosed in that...etc

Comment: Why do you need the “” after $0 in the awk example?

Comment: That is to guard against the possibility of a false match when str is 0 and $0 is an empty line. We coerce a string comparison at all times by doing this.

Answer (score 4):

I'd use `perl`:

```
$ perl -0777 -ne 'print $3 while /^((\S)\2+\n)(.*?)^\1/smg' < your-file
This is a test
Another test
Last test
```

Or `pcregrep`:

```
$ pcregrep -Mo3 '(?s)^((\S)\2+\n)(.*?)\n?^\1' < your-file
This is a test
Another test
Last test
```

If it's only about returning what's between fixed delimiters:

```
$ pcregrep -Mo1 '(?s)^==\n(.*?)\n?^==$' < your-file
Last test
```

Comment: I would prefer if it only outputs *one* result depending on the number of repeated char used. eg: if you use "==" as input, then it would only output the "Last test" string, without outputting anything else...etc

Answer (score 3):

Seems like your question wasn't clear and you got various types of solution. To get only content surrounded by `==` with `GNU sed` (syntax/feature might vary with other implementations):

```bsh
$ sed -n '/^==$/,//{//!p}' testfile
Last test
```

`sed` has a way to select a range of lines by specifying two *addresses* separated by a comma. To avoid repeating the regexp you can use `//` here. Since you do not want the marker lines themselves in the output, you can negate those matches. `{}` is used to group commands to be executed only for the matching lines.

Answer (score 2):

command:

```
awk '{a[++i]=$0}/==/{for(x=NR-1;x<NR;x++)print a[x]}' filename|sed '/^$/d'
```

output

```
This is a test
Another test
Last test
```

Comment: Yes, but i need only *one* output (see the comment on the other answer). And only if I use a specific pattern like say "==" instead of the other one in the example, then it would only output "Last test"

Answer (score 2):

In case the input file is guaranteed to have empty lines between the enclosed content it doesn't include lines having only `--`, which is the case with `testfile`, there is grep-only solution:

```
$grep -A 1 '^==$' testfile | grep -v '^==$' | grep -v '^--$' | grep .
Last test
```

- `grep -A 1 '^==$'` will print one line after matching the string enclosing the content
- `grep -v '^==$'` will remove the lines in the result which contain the string enclosing the content
- `grep -v '^--$'` will remove the group separator which would appear in the result when using the `-A` option
- `grep .` will filter out only the lines containing at least one character which will remove the empty lines